# EBS snapshots is there such a thing as incremental vs full?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I understand that the very first snapshot is a full snapshot. Therefore each subsequent snapshot is incremental. With that said, in this scenario, I assume I shouldn't delete the first snapshot. If I had to restore the "latest" data set, I would need to load from the last snapshot, correct?

Now what would happen if I delete the first snapshot? I take a third snapshot, would I be able to restore from the second snapshot? I guess where I'm going with all this is, if I only need the latest snapshot at any given time, can I delete all previous snapshot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't something you can control. Snapshot whenever you like, delete whatever snapshots you like including the original, AWS will ensure they have all the data required to restore from any snapshots listed on your account.

Think of the snapshots as deduplicated rather than full plus incremental. When you create a snapshot any blocks that already exist aren't stored, they're referenced. When you delete a snapshot any blocks in use by other snapshots aren't deleted.

You can read more about this in the [AWS EBS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSSnapshots.html#how_snapshots_work).

Comment: the effect is like the 2nd snapshot becoming a full snapshot.  the snapshots you see are just point-in-time references, not individual collections of blocks.

Comment: Effectively, yes.